# PS3 controller to Ubuntu 21

Tags: bluetooth, 21.04, 21.10, ps3

How to connect Dualshock3 to Ubuntu 21? There's a lot of tutorials for older versions of Ubuntu of which I couldn't find the solution. The generic solution would be through `bluetoothctl` alas, I couldn't find the controller with it.

How to find the controller? Any other possible solutions I should look into?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: There is no Ubuntu 21; Ubuntu has reserved the *year* format for *snap* only products such as Ubuntu Core 20; with the *year.month* format products for the far more widely used *deb* based products that can also use *snap* packages; ie. 20 & 20.04 are different products.  The *year* products are smaller, less flexible/powerful - but that's also a strength (for device/appliance/cloud use as faster to start!) so I'd suggest using a *deb* based product instead of *year* system,

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to put your controller in pairing mode and connect via Bluetooth.
If this doesn't work, try using a wired connection.

Comment: How to put it into pairing mode?